# SendGrid email showing "Accepted" but never arrives

Tags: c#, .net, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am new to Sendgrid and have made a small console app to test it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Execute().Wait();
}

static async Task Execute()
{
    try
    {
        var apiKey = "XX.XXXXXX-R-XXXXXX_XXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress(xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com", "Me");
        var subject = "Test";
        var to = new EmailAddress("xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com", "You");
        var plainTextContent = "Test";
        var htmlContent = "Test";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
        Console.Read();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get output which suggests it has been accepted (there are no errors, and the StatusCode is accepted):

```
Accepted

Connection: keep-alive
X-Message-Id: N2e7faW9TuC38K25dUVFlQ
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
Date: Tue, 28 Nov 2017 15:24:32 GMT
Server: nginx
```

but I never receive the email, and the stats on SendGrid show 0 mails sent.

I've checked Junk, Clutter, Anti-Spam and the message definitely isn't arriving. What am I missing?

Comment: Does it show up in [the activity list](https://app.sendgrid.com/email_activity) at all? Is the address possibly in the [unsubcribes list](https://app.sendgrid.com/suppressions/global_unsubscribes) from your testing? Have you given it a few hours for Sendgrid's asynchronous stats to catch up?

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server you host you can monitor to at least see if its trying to connect and its not currently in a queue?

Comment: @BugFinder If I'm reading the code correctly, they're using the Sendgrid REST API. No SMTP involvement at all there.

Comment: @BugFinder -  the above comment is right, it's the API, not SMTP.

Comment: @Ben no but the mail receiving would be SMTP - so that would tell you if its held in a queue at the sendgrid end if you can see it connecting and failing

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean. It's coming in through Mimecast + Office 365, so no SMTP server as such. However, have used Mimecast's monitoring tools and can't see anything.

Comment: @ceejayoz - nothing set at all in Unsubscribes (literally only set up a trial account this morning). Can't see anything on the activity list either.

Comment: In my experience, Sendgrid's admin can be 1-2 hours behind. Some sort of batch job doing stats runs, I'd imagine.

Comment: good to know. How about the mail delivery - is that fairly instant or should I expect a delay on that too?

Comment: That's going to depend on the recipient's mail server. Remember that spam detection can play a role here - sometimes emails disappearing means it was nixed by the receiving server somewhere along the way.

Comment: @Ben Did you solved the issue? I have exactly the same problem, and I don't have any idea how to solve it.

Comment: @Ben did you ever figure this out?  I see mine will go through to my gmail account but not my Hotmail account.  SendGrid says they were delivered but never shows up.